# Need help storing a value I get from a sqlite3 DB in a C++ variable

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm having a 'Data.db' with 3 tables in it that store some kind of 'football data'.
One table is for 'teams' and another one is for 'players'. What I want to do now is to get the 'highest' ID from 'Teams' so I can assign newly generated players to that team.
(Every player has a _teamId)

I am able to print the ID I want by using this query and a callback_id that prints just the value I need.

Query:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TEAMS;";

highest_id = (sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), callback_id, 0, &messageError));
```

Callback:

```
int Team::callback_id(void* data, int count, char** values, char** columns) {
    int id = atoi(values[1]);

    std::cout << "callback_id says: " << id << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What do I have to do to store this id from my callback function in a variable that I can use later in my program? It seems like I can't just return it and I can't just assign the id value to my `Team::_id` as it gives me an error:
`'invalid use of member ‘Team::_id’ in static member function'`

Help would be much appreciated. I'm still trying to learn more about sqlite3 and the callback function in particular but I've wasted so much time on this problem that I don't know what else I could try.

Comment: The void* pointer is often used in C libraries to provide a context to the function operation. You can consider it an expanded version of the `this` pointer. You should be able to put your c++ object there and store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `void*` argument in `sqlite3_exec` which you currently set to `0`. Instead, pass a pointer to an object there. This makes it possible to store what you like in that object in the callback.

One often passes a pointer to an object and call a non-`static` member function in that object to deal with the callback.

Example:

```
class Team {
public:
    void func() {
        std::string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TEAMS;";
        sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), &Team::callback_id_proxy, this, &messageError);
        //                                                        ^^^^
    }

    // a static callback proxy, casting `data` to a `Team*`
    static int callback_id_proxy(void* data, int count, char** values, char** columns) {
        return static_cast<Team*>(data)->callback_id(count, values, columns);
    }

    int callback_id(int count, char** values, char** columns) {
        // here you can store what you like in your `Team` object
        if(count > 0) highest_id = atoi(values[0]);
        else highest_id = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    int highest_id;
};
```

Note: You may want to use `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEAMS;` instead. Otherwise, you may get duplicates if you delete a team and then add a new team.

Another option is to make `func` and `highest_id` `static` too. I've renamed `highest_id` into `number_of_teams` here, because that's what it really is.

```
class Team {
public:
    static int get_number_of_teams() {
        std::string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TEAMS;";
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(),
                        &Team::callback_count,
                        nullptr,    // static function, no "this" available
                        &messageError) == SQLITE_ABORT)
            throw std::runtime_error("callback_id returned non-zero");

        return number_of_teams;
    }

    static int callback_count(void* data, int count, char** values, char** columns) {
        if(count > 0) {
            number_of_teams = atoi(values[0]);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1; // indicate error
    }

private:
    inline static int number_of_teams = -1;
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help. I tried it the way you suggested but somehow I always get the same value of 7 somehow. I don't know where it comes from but it doesn't change no matter how many teams are stored in my 'Teams' table. Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Also I put a `std::cout << "ID in callback_id: " << atoi(values[0]) << std::endl;` in my callback_id to find my msitake but it never prints anything to the console. Am I calling the function wrong (Do I have to add anything to your callback_id_proxy?) I'm obviously pretty new to C++ and not to familiar with static_cast or '->'

Comment: @Embrano No, `callback_id_proxy` should be complete as-is in my answer. What does `count` say if you print it in `callback_id`? It should be only `1` if all is working. Also, print the values without conversion: `for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) std::cout << '>' << values[i] << "<\n";` to see if that reveals anything

Comment: Also: You've made `func()` into a member function in `Team`, right?

Comment: omg... I feel so stupid now.. count didn't say anything just like my "ID in callback_id:" didn't say anything. I cross checked everything with some earlier drafts of this sh** I made and realized that there was no 'sqlite3_open("Data.db", &db)' anywhere in sight. I added it in the func() and voila, everything you gave me worked like a charm. It gave me the correct ID and the new players I generated had the correct team_id as well.

Comment: @Embrano Oh, glad it worked out - you're welcome. Another idea is to make `func` and `highest_id` `static` too since they are not really interesting for an individual `Team`. I'll add that option in a few minutes.